# reference about slant product

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I'm recently study the orientation of ASD moduli space, which involved some techniques about slant product in algebraic topology.

However I never heard about this kind of product before. So I wonder if anyone can give me a friendly reference(I'm not good at algebraic topology) or introducing something basic about slant product to me in the answer.

I'll be really appreciated if anyone can help me.